# Array doesn't retain its value after being written to

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to read a file into an array, each line will be store in an index of the array. Given the following input in the text.txt file :

```
6afe
5af
3eafe
7fae
3sfs
1eef
```

I read into the array, then printout the array in the console to check, but somehow the array doesn't retain its value after the loop. The output I got was null, before and after, but not in middle of the loop. Please tell me why ? Thank you 
Here are the output I get

```
nullline 0
nullline four
6afe
5af
3eafe
7fae
3sfs
1eef
nullline three
nullline four
```

The output I epxected to get are :

```
nullline 0             // array still empty here, i get it
    nullline four     // array still empty
    6afe         
    5af
    3eafe
    7fae
    3sfs
    1eef
    7fae      // where here are null three ? in the actual ouput
    3sfs      // null three ?
```

And here is my code :

```
import java.io.*;

public class readSortWrite
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        //input file
        // to count lineNum
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("text.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //to read into array names[]
        FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("text.txt");
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);

        // output file
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("sorted.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

        // counting number of line
        int lineNum = 0;
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            lineNum++;
            line = br.readLine();            
        }
        pw.close();
       // System.out.println(lineNum + "lines");  

        // create an array of of lineNum size and write each line of file into array
        String[] names = new String[lineNum];
        String str;
        str = br1.readLine();

        System.out.println(names[0]+ " line 0");
        System.out.println(names[4] + " line four");

        for (int i = 0 ; i<lineNum; i++)
        {
            while (str!= null)
            {
                names[i] = str;
                str = br1.readLine();
                System.out.println(names[i]);


            }             
        }
       // fr1.close();
        System.out.println(names[3]+ " line three");
        System.out.println(names[4] + " line four");



    }
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You have a while loop inside a for loop, do you understand what happens then? Have you read the documentation for BufferedReader and readLine()?

Comment: Here is also a useful read on importance of debugging your failing code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first 2 lines are `null` cause you create the array and print the values at `0` and `4` indices before init them, like so

```
String[] names = new String[lineNum];
String str;
str = br1.readLine();

System.out.println(names[0]+ " line 0");
System.out.println(names[4] + " line four");
```

for the second last rows, the `while` loop will read the `buffer` till it empty but without any iteration of the `for` loop, thus only populated `names[0]`

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<lineNum; i++)
{
  while (str!= null)
  {
    names[i] = str;
    str = br1.readLine();
    System.out.println(names[i]); 
  }             
}
```

change it to something like

```
int i =0;
while (str!= null && i < lineNum) {
  names[i] = str;
  str = br1.readLine();
  System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the nested loops used to read the file into array

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i<lineNum; i++)
    {
        while (str!= null)
        {
            names[i] = str;
            str = br1.readLine();
            System.out.println(names[i]);


        }             
    }
```

so for the first value of `i` you read The **entire** input file. when you wxit the nested `while` loop, the entire file has been read, but the index remained the same.

yuo should have one loop that reads the file, and the index is advanced at each iteration

```
    int i = 0;
    while (str!= null)
    {
        names[i] = str;
        i++;
        str = br1.readLine();
        System.out.println(names[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare and instantiate names:

```
 String[] names = new String[lineNum];
```

but after that you haven't put anything into names when you try to print:

```
System.out.println(names[0]+ " line 0");
System.out.println(names[4] + " line four");
```

In the for loop that follows you are overwriting names[0] repeatedly. The while loop executes using 0 as the value of i.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it with the code below. You were using a while true

```
    String str;

    System.out.println(names[0]+ " line 0");
    System.out.println(names[4] + " line four");

    for (int i = 0 ; i<lineNum; i++)
    {
        str = br1.readLine();

        if (str!= null)
        {
            names[i] = str;
            System.out.println(names[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] names = new String[lineNum];
        String str;
        str = br1.readLine();

        System.out.println(names[0]+ " line 0");
        System.out.println(names[4] + " line four");
```

the code you just create names[], so output is null.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<lineNum; i++)
        {
            while (str!= null)
            {
                names[i] = str;
                str = br1.readLine();
                System.out.println(names[i]);


            }             
        }
```

the code ,when i=0 ,you enter while and not break,so System.out.println(names[i]); always output names[0] until the last str.
and names[] other element is always null.